# Eloquent sortBy() accessor does not order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I need to be able to order a Collection by an attribute that is defined via an accessor. I'm struggling with it and I can't really understand why it doesn't work properly.

Here are some snippets of my code:

> web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

> HomeController.php

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $drivers = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
                $q->where('slug', 'driver');
            })->get();

    $sorteddrivers = $drivers->sortBy('last_free_time');

    $rides = Ride::all();
    return view('dashboard')->with('rides', $rides)->with('drivers', $sorteddrivers);
}
```

> User.php

```
function getLastFreeTimeAttribute($driver_id)
{
    return UserController::lastFreeTime($driver_id);
}
```

> UserController.php

```
public static function lastFreeTime($driver_id)
{
    // $result = Ride::with('driver')->orderBy('arrival','desc')->first();
    $result = DB::table('rides')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'rides.user_id')
        ->select('rides.arrival')
        ->where('users.id','=',$driver_id)
        ->orderBy('rides.arrival', 'asc')
        ->first();

    if (is_null($result)) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($result->arrival)->format('H:i');
    }
}
```

> dashboard.blade.php

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($drivers as $driver)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $driver->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ App\Http\Controllers\UserController::lastFreeTime($driver->id) }}</td>
            <td>
                @if(  \App\Http\Controllers\UserController::isDriving($driver->id) )
                    <span class="bg-danger text-white p-1"><i class="fa fas fa-car fa-lg"></i> Busy</span>
                @else
                    <span class="bg-success text-white p-1"><i class="fa fas fa-car fa-lg"></i> Free</span>
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Line 8 of last code should be ordered, but it is not. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `->sortBy('last_free_time')` _before_ `->get()`?

Comment: That throws a Call to undefined method  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortby()

Comment: should be sortBy() - capital B @MarceloZárate

Comment: `getLastFreeTimeAttribute($driver_id)` doesn't work, `$driver_id` is always `null`. Where should the value come from?

Comment: whats do you get when you dd($drivers) before the sortBy()?

Comment: Does your Model `User` depend on a controller (`UserController`)?

Comment: I think `getLastFreeTimeAttribute($driver_id)` should just be `getLastFreeTimeAttribute()` (without the parameter), and you can pass `$this->id` from your `User` model to `lastFreeTime()`: `public function getLastFreeTimeAttribute(){ return UserController::lastFreeTime($this->id); }` Currently, it's likely that `last_free_time` is `null`, or otherwise un-sortable, so while the `sortBy()` function is working, it isn't doing anything noticeable.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir you are right about that, thanks a lot.

Comment: @TimLewis please provide it like an answer, so I can mark it. Worked as expected, how could I not see that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a parameter to a `get...Attribute()` function is not supported (at least to my knowledge), but `$this`, which references the current `User` (called `$driver`) is, so you can refactor:

```
public function getLastFreeTimeAttribute(){ 
  return UserController::lastFreeTime($this->id); 
}
```

The `sortBy()` method was working correctly, but since `last_free_time` was `null`, it wasn't doing anything noticeable. This should work correctly now.